# How do I put CodeIgniter's/TankAuth's register and login forms on the same page?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authorization, registration, tankauth

I'm using CodeIgniter for my php framework and TankAuth for my authorization/registration.  By default, TankAuth places the registration and login forms on separate pages.  I would like to place the log-in form in the navigation bar that occurs on every page.  There is also a sign-up page that will have the registration form occurring simultaneously as the log-in form (located in the navbar).

I am currently using this in controllers/signup.php .index()...

```
            $this -> load -> view('templates/header');
            $this -> login();
            $this -> register();
            $this -> load -> view('templates/footer');
```

This displays correctly but I have two issues:

1  Will I have to redefine TankAuth's methods in every controller that will have the log-in form?

2  When I try to register it tells me that the log-in form should be filled out as well.  That's obviously a catch-22.

(I apologize if this is too domain specific or vague; I hope it makes sense to those who have worked with the framework.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by just *combining* login & register views, they were not designed to work together, so you definetly need to do some modifications to the base **tank auth** structure.

This really shouldn't be a confusing issue as its just a problem you created for yourself by combining two very similar forms.

To simply walk through this, (and I don't know what code changes if any you made) first you must create your own login (html), set the form `action="/auth/login"`.

The login will submit, **IF** it is all clear the user is logged in and you handle it like that, **HOWEVER** if they fail to login, they will be brought to a single page login (default/or modified) where they can re-try again.

The same should follow for registration, set the form `action="/auth/register"` and let it submit against **tank auth** controller.  Again, if registration is successfull, they will just get shuttled through wherever, otherwise brought to a single registration page.

Use the original **login** and **registration** views as a start to what you need to change / update.

**Tank Auth** is really a plugin, that you need to modify to suit your needs, its code is clean and clear, so just go through it so you understand what happens at login, what happens at registration, activation etc, otherwise mashing things together will not get you anywhere. In my personal experience with the library, I have ALWAYS modified it beyond the initial setup, just because it is simple to do.

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I meant but it's helped me more than what I was originally looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is still an issue but if you really want to do that, you can include one view in another as an `IFRAME` without any issues.